# Проверить числовой ряд на чередование знака

Tags: python, list, tuple

Программа запрашивает число n. Далее, мы вводим n чисел и сохраняем все введенные числа в массив. Программа должна проверить чередуются ли в нем положительные и отрицательные числа. Если чередуются, то вывести YES, иначе NO.

Ввод:
6
2 -8 1 5 3 22
Вывод:
NO

Ввод:
6
1 -2 2 -4 3 -20
Вывод:
YES

Не могу понять как прописать  это в условие - "**чередуются ли в нем положительные и отрицательные числа**".

Comment: https://pyprog.pro/mathematical_functions/sign.html умножайте sign предыдущего элемента на -1 и сравнивайте с sign текущего, если хоть один не равен, то ответ NO, иначе YES

Comment: какое отношение имеет название вопроса к его содержимому?

Comment: вопрос по теме "Списки(lists), кортежи (tuples)"

Comment: можно ли решить проще, без импорта numpy?

Comment: @DisplayedName, __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @DisplayedName Конечно, решение ниже не требует numpy.

Comment: @MaxU Здесь и не требуют решения, а просят пояснить условие, поэтому всё в рамках правил сообщества.

Comment: В одну строчку - `print(("NO","YES")[[all(map(lambda x: x[0]*x[1]<0, zip(x, x[1:]))) for x,x in [(input(), list(map(int, input().split())))]][0]])`.

Comment: @GrAnd ага. В вас я не сомневался :))

Answer (score 2):

### Приведу алгоритм, код напишите сами:

- если 0 в списке, то сразу пишем `NO`
- `i` идёт от 0 до (длины списка - 1):

  - если `i`-ый элемент, делённый на `i+1` элемент больше нуля, то пишем `NO` и выходим из цикла
- если мы не писали `NO`, то пишем `YES`

> если мы не писали `NO`, то пишем `YES`

Это вы можете сделать с помощью флажка с логическим значением

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_num(num, next_is_negative):
    if next_is_negative and num < 0:
        return True
    elif not next_is_negative and num > 0:
        return True
    return False

def is_alternates(l):

    # Смотрим каким должно быть второе число
    # Если первое больше 0, то второе должно быть меньше и наоборот
    next_is_negative = l[0] > 0

    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        num = l[i]
        if not check_num(num, next_is_negative):
            return False
           
        # Теперь у следующего числа должен быть противоположный знак
        next_is_negative = not next_is_negative
            
    return True


l = [6, 2, -8, 1, 5, 3, 22]
print(is_alternates(l)) # False
l = [-6, -2, 8, -1, -5, -3, -22]
print(is_alternates(l)) # False
l = [6, -2, 8, -1, 5, -3, 22]
print(is_alternates(l)) # True
l = [-6, 2, -8, 1, -5, 3, -22]
print(is_alternates(l)) # True
```

Comment: Зачем давать ответ людям, которые не хотят учиться? Минус от меня

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8, как по мне, если бы он не хотел учиться, то ему было бы проще обратится к одногруппникам, что бы вместо него написали всю программу. Если он знает про stack overflow, значит он хотя бы пытался сам что-то сделать. Когда начинал учить свой первый язык программирования, я нуждался в таких ответах, ибо не хватало практически навыков

Answer (score -1):

```
a = []

n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))

a = [abs(x) for x in a]
b = set(a)

if len(a) == len(b):
    print('NO')
else:
    print('YES')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Зачем давать ответ людям, которые не хотят учиться? Минус от меня. К тому же, можно сделать проще